# If network speed is less than 1kb/s then why SFTP connection fails more frequently

Tags: networking, ssh, sftp, openssh

If network speed is less than 1kb/s then why SFTP connection fails more frequently.

If i increase network speed then no sftp connection fails.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a timeout problem. Your slower connection probably causes the SSH connection to reset. Try adding

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

in your `ssh_config`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also using an sftp client that can recover from broken connections as for instance [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/).